# if there are three strings, randomly pair the 6 ends together, what is the probability of getting a complete circle

Tags: combinatorics

I try to use recursive formula to solve it, but I do not know whether it is right or not. I let Pn be the probability of getting a complete circle with n strings. Then I consider the situation when I add one more string. The first end of the string can be attached to any other ends, but the second end of the new string can only attached to one end.(Imaging inserting the new string into the circle). It gives the recursive formula Pn=Pn-1/2n-1.

Comment: Can you connect one end of a string to its other end?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have $P_1=1$.

Assume that there are $n\geq2$ strings. We select a random pair of the $2n$ ends. This can be done in ${2n\choose2}$ ways. When the two chosen ends belong to the same string we have a failure. There are $n$ failure pairs, so that with probability
$$1-{n\over{2n\choose2}}={2n-2\over2n-1}$$
we are successful. Conditioned on this happening we now have $n-1$ strings, not all of the same length. The probability that a random pairing of the $2n-2$ ends of these strings leads to a success is $P_{n-1}$. It follows that we have the recursion
$$P_n={2n-2\over2n-1}\,P_{n-1}\qquad(n\geq2)\ .$$
One can easily find an expression of $P_n$ in terms of factorials and powers of two. The numerical values are
$$(P_n)_{n\geq1}=\left(1,{2\over3},{8\over15},{16\over35},{128\over315},{256\over693},\ldots\right)\ .$$